# When trying to create an instance of UserControl, getting NullPointerException

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

When I'm trying to use a `UserControl` which is in the same solution, I'm getting `NullPointerException` in `InitializeComponent()` line.

My `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file where I'm adding `UserControl`:

```
ViewStudentUc viewStudentUc = new ViewStudentUc();
viewStudentGrid.Children.Add(viewStudentUc);
```

My `ViewStudentUc.xaml` file where I'm getting exception:

```
public ViewStudentUc()
{
    InitializeComponent();   //Where I'm getting NullPointerException.
}
```

Why am I getting this exception and how can I remove it?

This is the call stack.

```
SNS School Management.exe!SNS_School_Management.ViewStudentUc.ViewStudentUc() Line 25   C#
SNS School Management.exe!SNS_School_Management.MainWindow.viewStudent_button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 39 + 0x15 bytes   C#
[External Code]
```

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace.

Comment: You have an invalid object in the .Designer.CS file. I know normally you don't go editing that file... but happens quite often for me.

Comment: This is tagged as wpf so there is no designer.cs. In which method is the code that creates the new component? Can you debug?

Comment: This is an event when a button is clicked then I'm trying to hide previous grid and replace it by this User Control.

Comment: @Nitin: It sounds very odd - can you post a *full* solution somewhere? (Ideally one which doesn't have any non-essential code in.)

Comment: yeah.. Just tell me where or how.

Comment: Well, Solved the problem. It had some runtime error in the 'User Control' that I made. It wasn't showing any error but at runtime it couldn't make the object for User Control. I corrected the code in xaml file and it worked fine.